# How to use UIActivityIndicator as a status indicator in real time for iOS?

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

]]I am trying to build a UIActivityIndicator for my iOS app so that it is displaying the current state of certain processes that are running, and each quarter segment of the wheel will be highlighted by a different colour, depending on the status.

All of the tutorials I have seen show how to build an activity indicator that spins while something is loading, whereas I need the indicator to remain on the screen and show state.  I need the indicator to remain hollow, with only the circumference that is coloured.  How would I do this?

Comment: Thanks, I honestly didn't know that.  I'll look into this.  Thanks again.

Comment: How do I mark this question as being answered?

Comment: I've answered it now so you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core graphics. You'll have to make a custom class that inherits from `UIView` and do all the drawing yourself. You'll probably override a setter for a float `(progress)`, which will update the display (using `[self setNeedsDisplay]`. Then in the drawRect: method you'll use this class property of `progress` to determine what color and what angle to draw/fill in the view. Check out the source of MBProgressHud for some reference: [MBProgressHUD](http://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/blob/master/MBProgressHUD.m)